# Can stack _not_ squelch output when building multiple targets?

Tags: haskell-stack

When using stack in a project with multiple cabal files, there seems to be a difference in verbosity when using a stack command on a single target vs multiple targets.

This seems to happen for all sorts of stack commands, so I'll just give a few examples.

With `stack build sub-project-1`, stack will show progress on each of the modules it compiles. But `stack build sub-project-1 sub-project-2` or `stack build` will suddenly show only which target it is working on and not show any of the modules it is working on.

Another example I have found recently is in `stack test`. I wanted to get a full list of all the Tasty tests I have, so I ran `stack test --test-arguments="-l"`. But all it printed out was:

```
sub-project-1-0.0.0.1: test (suite: run-tests, args: -l)
sub-project-2-0.0.0.1: test (suite: run-tests, args: -l)
Completed 2 action(s).
Log files have been written to: /projdir/.stack-work/logs/
```

Even if I manually specify the targets I want eg:`stack test sub-project-1 sub-project-2 --test-arguments="-l"`, it gives me the same unhelpful output.

I have to run stack with exactly one target: `stack test sub-project-1 --test-arguments="-l"` to get any of the output I am looking for:

```
sub-project-1-0.0.0.1: test (suite: run-tests, args: -l)

all tests/tasty tests/this is a test
all tests/tasty tests/this is another test
```

Is there anything I can do to get stack to not squelch the output when running against more than one package? Stack verbosity levels don't seem to have anything to do with this. They seem to consider `-v` to mean "print out debugging statements"

Comment: Try the `--dump-logs` flag. If that doesn't work for you, maybe chime in [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/426).

Comment: Thanks: `--dump-logs` works for me. Now, for stackoverflow etiquette, do I write the answer or do you?

Comment: Please go ahead, write an answer and mark it solved! Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to sjakobi for the suggestion.

Recent versions of stack have an option: `--dump-logs`

This option will show the output from each action stack takes on each target.